# While loop inside while loop JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

How do I use while loop inside while loop without executing the next loop (from outside while loop) unless the inner while loop done executing?

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
while(x < 10){
   while(y < 10){
      console.log(y);
      y++;
   }
  x++;
}
```

Comment: I've got trouble understanding what you are asking. What is supposed to be the outcome of your code there?

Comment: put `y=0;` before x++

Comment: That's what it does now; the entire inner loop will run before the next iteration of the outer loop. What's your specific issue? Not resetting the `y` counter value?

Comment: not sure what you're asking but i bet the answer is either `break;` or `continue;`

Comment: ex. the outer loop execute first, then the second loop execute too. but before the outer loop iterate again through x++, the inner loop should finish looping first.

Comment: Trust me i am very confused by this question

Comment: @TariiqHenryBbosa me too :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your problem here is that at the end of the inner loop, `y` is set to `10` and it never is reset to 0. Try this instead:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
while(x < 10){
   while(y < 10){
      console.log(y);
      y++;
   }
  y = 0;
  x++;
}
```

Otherwise, once the inner loop finishes once, it never runs again.

Comment: Just a pointer, instead of setting `y=0` after loop, move declaration of `y` inside loop as `var y = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Put `y` initialization inside first while loop.

```
var x = 0;
while(x < 10){
   var y = 0;
   while(y < 10){
      console.log(y);
      y++;
   }
   x++;
}
```

Comment: Yah maybe that was what he wanted