# while loop, JavaScript printing unexpected value

Tags: javascript

I have gone through this Question and Answer [While loop inside while loop JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40661321/while-loop-inside-while-loop-javascript)

```
function getMaxLessThanK(n, k) {

  let i = 1;

  while (i < n) {
    let j = i + 1;
    while (j < n + 1) {
      console.log(i, j)
      j++
    }
    i++
  }
}
```

when n = 5, what am I getting is

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
2 3
2 4
2 5
3 4
3 5
4 5
undefined
```

How to avoid this the last line `undefined`. what is the reason for it?

Can anyone help on this please?

Edit:

This is what the actual thing I am doing below.

[image]

Comment: is it from this code block or someplace else your using this function which is printing this

Comment: Do you also log the result of the function call? Like `console.log(getMaxLessThanK(5))`? Your function returns `undefined`.

Comment: No, I my self wrote this code while trying to solve one of the HackerRank Question

Comment: @Ram yes, exactly, `n  =5, k=4, console.log(getMaxLessThanK(n)`

Comment: So this is because you are logging the returned value of the function which is `undefined`. This is the answer you are looking for. `undefined` is not an unexpected value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running it in a console and get an `undefined` like this：

[image]

This `undefined` indicates that your statement runs without returning a value. It's not a result of your `console.log`.

If you make the function return something:

```js
function getMaxLessThanK(n, k) {

  let i = 1;

  while (i < n) {
    let j = i + 1;
    while (j < n + 1) {
      console.log(i, j)
      j++
    }
    i++
  }
    return 'return value';
}
```

Then you'll get

[image]

Comment: Thank You. I got the concept with your answer.